# Awesome window manager doesn't react on clicks at toolbar when Caps Lock is on

Tags: awesome-wm

The title pretty much explains it. I use Caps Lock to change layouts, setting it with

```
awful.util.spawn_with_shell("setxkbmap -layout 'us, ru' -option 'grp:caps_toggle'")
```

in awesome's rc.lua, if that has anything to do with the issue. When Caps is on, neither tag tabs nor window tabs get selected when I click on them. Any ideas why is it this way?

Update: Versions of dependencies.

```
user@desktop:~$ dpkg -l | grep -E "(libc6)|(libcairo2)|(libdbus-1-3)|(libev4)|(libglib2.0-0)|(libimlib2)|(liblua5.1-0)|(libpango1.0-0)|(libstartup-notification0)|(libx11-6)|(libxcb-icccm4)|(libxcb-image0)|(libxcb-keysyms1)|(libxcb-randr0)|(libxcb-shape0)|(libxcb-util0)|(libxcb-xinerama0)|(libxcb-xtest0)|(libxcb1)|(libxdg-basedir1)|(dbus-x11)"
dbus-x11                                  1.6.4-1ubuntu4     
libc6:i386                                2.15-0ubuntu20     
libc6-dev:i386                            2.15-0ubuntu20             
libcairo2:i386                            1.12.2-1ubuntu2.2     
libdbus-1-3:i386                          1.6.4-1ubuntu4   
libev4                                    1:4.11-1                  
libglib2.0-0:i386                         2.34.1-1ubuntu1    
libimlib2                                 1.4.5-1ubuntu1   
liblua5.1-0:i386                          5.1.5-4          
libpango1.0-0:i386                        1.30.1-0ubuntu3   
libstartup-notification0:i386             0.12-1ubuntu2     
libx11-6:i386                             2:1.5.0-1     
libxcb-icccm4:i386                        0.3.9-2     
libxcb-image0:i386                        0.3.9-1     
libxcb-keysyms1:i386                      0.3.9-1     
libxcb-randr0:i386                        1.8.1-1ubuntu1 
libxcb-shape0:i386                        1.8.1-1ubuntu1  
libxcb-util0:i386                         0.3.8-2build1        
libxcb-xinerama0:i386                     1.8.1-1ubuntu1    
libxcb-xtest0:i386                        1.8.1-1ubuntu1  
libxcb1:i386                              1.8.1-1ubuntu1   
libxcb1-dev:i386                          1.8.1-1ubuntu1   
libxdg-basedir1                           1.1.1-2
```

UPDATE 2:
Output of xev on clicks with Caps on and off (the only difference is "state")

Caps Off:

```
LeaveNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x25f, subw 0x0, time 47184554, (49,24), root:(51,45),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 256

ButtonPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x25f, subw 0x1200002, time 47184553, (49,24), root:(51,45),
    state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES

EnterNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x25f, subw 0x0, time 47184554, (49,24), root:(51,45),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 256
```

Caps On:

```
LeaveNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x25f, subw 0x0, time 47185737, (49,24), root:(51,45),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 8448

ButtonPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x25f, subw 0x1200002, time 47185737, (49,24), root:(51,45),
    state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES

EnterNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x25f, subw 0x0, time 47185737, (49,24), root:(51,45),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 8448
```

Comment: Which distro are you using and what are the versions of the dependencies of awesome? First thing would be to try updating the system. I rememeber having something similar a while ago.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10, had the same issue on Ubuntu 10.04 (12.04 is not upgraded, but freshly installed). Added the list of dependencies versions to the post. The system is regularly updated.

Comment: Weird. I can't reproduce with awesome 3.4.9-1, Ubuntu 11.04. Look for differences in mouse click events with caps on vs off with `xev`? See if `xkeycaps` shows anything weird? What if you reverse the order of `'us, ru'`, does awesome then not work with caps-lock off? What if you remove the call to `setxkbmap` entirely?