# Awesome WM ignores input in non-us layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, awesome-wm

I've started using **Awesome WM**, and found annoying that it ignores input in "Run" widget (`mod+R`) when current layout is not **US**, say, **RU**. Also, it ignores and *any* input (mouse klicks, keyboard - even not layout-specific keys like Esc!) in its launcher/mainmenu and "clients list" and so on.
I'm using Arch Linux, and `~/.xinitrc` has following line:

```
setxkbmap -layout "us, ru" -option "grp:caps_toggle, grp_led:caps"
```

Awesome's `rc.lua` default config has neither layout, nor capslock-specific things, but I tried to isolate problem and removed capslock toggle option from my xinitrc. This didn't help at all.

`xev` output shows that only thing changes when I switch layout (with capslock) is 'state':

-- left mouse click (current layout: US, everything is OK) --

```
LeaveNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13419931, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 256

EnterNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13419931, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 256

KeymapNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967189 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

ButtonPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13419931, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13420028, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x100, button 1, same_screen YES
```

-- caps lock (change layout US -> RU) --

```
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13420911, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13420998, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x2000, keycode 66 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

-- left mouse click (now Awesome can't see mouse clicks in its widgets/dialogs/...) --

```
LeaveNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13422624, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 8448

EnterNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13422625, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 8448

KeymapNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967189 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

ButtonPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13422624, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13422721, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x2100, button 1, same_screen YES
```

-- caps lock (change layout RU -> US) --

```
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13423836, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x2000, keycode 66 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13423947, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

-- escape (for example, closes the awesome's mainmenu) --

```
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13426419, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x0, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13426514, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x0, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

-- caps lock (change layout US -> RU) --

```
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13427017, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13427096, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x2000, keycode 66 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

-- escape (ignored) --

```
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13427782, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x2000, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1600001,
    root 0x95, subw 0x0, time 13427877, (151,498), root:(835,518),
    state 0x2000, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

P.S.: I also wonder where to find key abbriveations for awesome (ex. <kbd>Shift_R</kbd>) and what exactly these Mod1, Mod2 etc mean.

UPD: It's mostly the same problem as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027324/awesome-window-manager-doesnt-react-on-clicks-at-toolbar-when-caps-lock-is-on), but author said only about capslock-toggling, not about default (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>) toggle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is apparently in this https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/29123.

Source: https://awesome.naquadah.org/bugs/index.php?do=details&task_id=982

Comment: And the simplest solution is to downgrade xorg-xkbcomp to version 1.2.3

Comment: The simplest solution is actually editing /usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/basic and removing or commenting out the "group [2-4] = AltGr;" lines (all three of them). Found out by following the links in this answer to X11 bug report.

Answer (score 2):

I'm duplicating a comment to the accepted answer here for better visibility.

A workaround is to edit file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/basic` and remove or comment out the lines:

```
group 2 = AltGr;
group 3 = AltGr;
group 4 = AltGr;
```

as suggested [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50611#c6)